# How to change numbers in a list to make it monotonically decreasing?

Tags: python

I have got a list:

```
first = [100, 110, 60]
```

How to make that: if the next number is greater than the previous one, then it is necessary to reduce this number like preceding number.
For example, the answer should be:

```
ans = [100, 100, 60]
```

The second example:

```
arr = [60,50,60]
ans = [60, 50, 50]
```

The third example:

```
arr = [20, 100, 150]
ans = [20, 20, 20]
```

I try to, but i think it's not good idea

```
for i in range(len(arr)-1):

    if arr[i] < arr[i+1]:
        answer.append(a[i+1] - 10)
    if arr[i] < arr[i+1]:
        answer.append(a[i])
    if arr[i] < arr [i+1]:
        answer.append(arr[-1])
```

Comment: Why do you have the same condition three times?

Comment: If you have input of [100, 110, 105, 90, 110]  - what should the output be?

Comment: I guess `[100, 100, 100, 90, 90]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will modify the list *in situ*:

```
def fix_list(_list):
    for i, v in enumerate(_list[1:], 1):
        _list[i] = min(v, _list[i-1])
    return _list


print(fix_list([100, 110, 60]))
print(fix_list([60, 50, 60]))
print(fix_list([20, 100, 150]))
```

**Output:**

```
[100, 100, 60]
[60, 50, 50]
[20, 20, 20]
```

Comment: *accumulate()* from itertools is faster - thank you @Konrad

Answer (score 7):

This is a special case of a [scan/prefix sum operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum), available in Python as `itertools.accumulate`:

```
ans = list(itertools.accumulate(arr, min))
```

Basically, this will output a list that, at each position, contains the minimum element of the input list up to that point.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work as following:

```py
list = [20, 100, 100]

out = list[0]

for x in range(len(list)-1):
   if list[x+1] > list[x]:
      out.append(list[x])
   else:
      out.append(list[x+1])

print(out)
```

Comment: there is typo in your code !

Answer (score 1):

Not a one liner, but maybe something like

```py
last = max(arr)
ans = []
for item in arr:
   last = min(last, item)
   ans.append(last)
```

Comment: I think it should only be lower or equal to the preveous number, not to the maximum.

Comment: The ``max`` is simply to make sure that the first ``min`` works as expected.  it's not looking for the maximum it goes through the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr1 = [50, 70, 10, 120, 150]
arr2 = []
for i, x in enumerate(arr1):
    if x <= arr1[i-1] or i==0:
        arr2.append(x)
    else:
        if x <= arr2[i-1]:
            arr2.append(arr1[i-1])
        else:
            arr2.append(arr2[i-1])
print(arr2)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative using **list comprehension**, for those that are interested.

```
ans = [min(arr[:i]) if i > 0 and a > min(arr[:i]) else a for i, a in enumerate(arr)]
```

Here is an example:

#### Code:

```py
arr = [100, 110, 105, 90, 110]
ans = [min(arr[:i]) if i > 0 and a > min(arr[:i]) else a for i, a in enumerate(arr)]
print(ans)
```

#### Output:

```
[100, 100, 100, 90, 90]
```

Comment: Nice one liner.  Just pointing out that if the list was to scale up, then constant call to min(arr[:i]) would not scale well.  But for smaller lists, probably doesn't matter.